# Phonegap Media API (Android) - Media is not defined

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, webview

I want to build a Android WebView app, which plays a sound when the user presses a button.For some reason I can't get the PhoneGap media API to work.

It keep showing:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined at
file:///android_asset/www/script.js:3
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/www/one.mp3");

  $('.one').click(function(){ 
    myMedia.play();
  });
});
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 19):

You might be trying to call `Media` before the deviceready event fires.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myMedia = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/www/one.mp3", 
        function(){
            if (myMedia) {
                myMedia.stop();
                myMedia.release();
            }
        }, 
        function(error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.one').click(function(event){ 
        myMedia.play();
    });
});

</script>
```