# Javascript can't find these variables, why?

Tags: javascript, cordova, logcat

I'm using Phonegap to create an Android application (Voice Recorder), but I had these 2 errors in my code:

1. `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Media.`
2. `TypeError: Result of expression 'mediaRec' undefined is not an object.`

The first error happens when the application runs. The second error happens when I call the recordAudio(); method.

Tell me what's the problem please if you know.

```
var mediaRec;
var src;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

}
function init() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Recording Status";
    src = "myrecording.mp3";
    mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
}

function recordAudio() {
    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// Stop audio
function stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRec) {
        mediaRec.stopRecord();
    }
    clearInterval(mediaTimer);
    mediaTimer = null;
}
// onSuccess Callback
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
}
// onError Callback 
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
// Set audio position
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('rec_position').innerHTML = position;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you expect the "Media" constructor to come from?  Have you used  something appropriate to import the package you need?

Comment: What should `Media` be? Obviously, there is no such constructor (and `mediaRec` will be `undefined` thereafter, throwing errors when accessing properties of it).

Comment: What is `Media`? Your errors are (not so clearly) telling you that it can't find a function named `Media`.

Comment: Also it probably should be `mediaRec.setAudioPosition()`

Comment: See this question: [Phonegap Media API (Android) - Media is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10186104/1169798).

Comment: @Pointy

Media is an API from Phonegap Library (Cordova, Phonegap)

Comment: @Bergi
Media is an API from Phonegap Library (Cordova, Phonegap)

Comment: @Pointy I edited the post check it again this method I already wrote and the error is not from it

Comment: @Sirko i checked that but the problem is not resolved

Comment: I actually think @Sirko might be right (and not just because I am the one that gave the answer to the other question). Try moving everything from `init()` to `onDeviceReady()`? Before `deviceready` fires, `Media` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scr = "/android_asset/www/myrecording.mp3" because directory phonegap in asset/www/...
If directory not found javascript in phonegap show alert like that ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Media.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the 'cordova-plugin-media' plugin which defines a global **Media** constructor. See [Cordova media documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/index.html)

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media --save`

The other reason this might happen is be sure to wait until device is ready Cordova event before `new Media` constructor is called.